# Getting count against the last execution date for each month, for a specific Site and Rule

Tags: excel, date, max

I have excel sheet data in format similar as mentioned below:
For each Site, a rule may be run multiple times in a month, I need to get the count of last execution each month, otherwise a count for that month should appear. Please provide some guidelines. I tried with Pivot table but unable to achieve this. Also trying with array formula... Will use for graph

```
RULE    SITE    COUNT   EXECUTEDON  COUNTER
PRK009  PARK    6215    30-Sep-2015 12:21:00 PM 1
PRK009  PARK    6259    19-Oct-2015 11:54:27 AM 2
PRK009  PARK    6259    02-Nov-2015 11:10:24 AM 3
PRK009  PARK    6274    30-Nov-2015 12:22:59 PM 5
PRK009  PARK    6264    16-Dec-2015 10:10:46 AM 6
PRK009  PARK    6264    29-Dec-2015 08:58:49 AM 7
PRK009  PARK    6265    19-Jan-2016 12:29:02 PM 8
PRK009  PARK    6297    31-Jan-2016 10:06:14 AM 9
PRK009  PARK    6313    07-Mar-2016 03:11:14 PM 10
PRK009  PARK    6368    18-Apr-2016 09:17:47 AM 11
PRK009  PARK    6527    11-May-2016 09:30:13 AM 12
AST046  BUHA    5645    18-Oct-2015 10:24:00 AM 1
AST046  BUHA    5601    02-Nov-2015 11:17:29 AM 2
AST046  BUHA    10  30-Nov-2015 03:04:30 PM 3
AST046  BUHA    10  16-Dec-2015 11:06:46 AM 4
AST046  BUHA    10  29-Dec-2015 11:00:23 AM 5
AST046  BUHA    10  19-Jan-2016 12:36:33 PM 6
AST046  BUHA    76  31-Jan-2016 10:13:44 AM 7
AST046  BUHA    82  07-Mar-2016 03:18:03 PM 8
AST046  BUHA    507 18-Apr-2016 09:24:27 AM 9
AST046  BUHA    807 11-May-2016 09:37:08 AM 10
```

Comment: Hi Andreas,

Thanks, I have to first select the Site, then its Rule and then its last executed count. 

You selected the first entry against AST046 and Last entry for PRK009. Still don't have a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

[image]

When you created your pivot table you can right click on the value column and there should be a value settings  or something like it. I have Swedish Excel so, not sure how it's translated. Maybe it's the third from the bottom of the right click menu.
In that settings you can set it to show max of count.

EDIT: see now that I may have selected the wrong row label. You wanted "Site"?
It should not make any difference of the answer.